# Run-time error '9' with a simple VBA copy sheet code

Tags: vba, excel

For some reason, I've been getting a run-time error 9: Subscript out of range with a simple copy sheet code and I can't seem to figure out why. Basically, I'm trying to copy Sheet1 from a file with the name "cash" in it to the current workbook (Daily Dashboard.xlsm) with the macro on a command button click. The following is are two codes I tried:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sPath As String, sName As String
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    sName = Dir(sPath & "cash*.xls?")
    If sName <> "" Then
        Windows(sName).Activate
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks("Daily Dashboard.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Cash & CC Sales"
    End If
End Sub
```

I thought may be the I need to actually open the workbook for this so I also tried the code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sPath As String, sName As String
    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    sName = Dir(sPath & "cash*.xls?")
    If sName <> "" Then
        Workbooks.Open (sName)
        Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks("Daily Dashboard.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Cash & CC Sales"
        Workbooks(sName).Close savechanges:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

In the second code, the file does open, but the copy part doesn't seem to work due to a run time error. Any ideas to what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: In the second one, try `Workbooks(sName).Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks("Daily Dashboard.xlsm").Sheets(Sheets.Count)`

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but still seem to get the same Run-Time error for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sheet references aren't quite right. Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sPath As String, sName As String

    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    sName = Dir(sPath & "cash*.xls?")

    If sName <> "" Then
        With Workbooks.Open(sName)
            .Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
            ActiveSheet.Name = "Cash & CC Sales"
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```